# Adding method that returns a Func to Entity Framework model causes InvalidOperationException exception

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class that I have used successfully as an Entity Framework model. I am using .Net Core 2. It has the primary key explicitly defined:

```
public partial class SsoProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    .... more properties
}
```

I then added this method to this SsoProfile class:

```
public Func<SsoProfile, IComparable> DefaultSortOrderSelector()
{
    return (SsoProfile x) => x.Id;
}
```

Now whenever I access the SsoProfile table via the SsoProfile class, I get the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type '<>c' requires a primary
>   key to be defined.

Same happens when I add this method:

```
public Func<int, IComparable> DefaultSortOrderSelector()
{
    return (int x) => x;
}
```

But when I add this method, there is no exception:

```
public int DefaultSortOrderSelector()
{
    return Id;
}
```

How can I add a method to an Entity Framework model class that returns a Func?

Comment: Can you show the code where you access the `SsoProfile` class? Maybe even how you use the problematic method? I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: How did you use the `Func<>`?Could you share more details?